# $(r+1)$ Clique of Induced subgraph and Turan’s theorem

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, extremal-graph-theory

$G$ is a $s$ regular graph.

$A$ is a set of vertices where $|A| = s$ and $A \subseteq G$.

$E$ is the number of edges of $G$.

$n$ is the total number of vertices of $G$.

**Problem:**  Find the lower bound of $E$ so that induced graph  $G-\{A\} $    has a $(r+1)$ clique where $r>1$.

**Proposed Solution:** Turan’s theorem states that  n-vertex simple graphs with no $(r + 1)$-cliques, then the number of edges

$E \leq  (1 -\frac{1}{r}) \frac{n^2}{2}$

If

$E > (1 -\frac{1}{r}) \frac{n^2}{2}$

Then for that particular $G$ with such $E$, ensures, for any arbitrary $A$ , $G-\{A\} $   has a $(r+1)$ clique where $r>1$.

**Question:**
1.  *Is the proposed solution correct?*

2. Is the proposed solution ‘rigorous’?
3. Is there an alternative way to prove (also the case if the proof is incorrect)?